# why prop value is changing with data changes in vuejs3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

props that I'm getting

```
props : {
     images : Object,
     locale : String,
},
```

data method

```
data() {
        return {
            form : this.$inertia.form({
                product_images : this.images.data,
            }),
        }
    },
```

I'm updating project_images on click event like so

```
Add() {
       this.form.product_images.push({image : null});
},
```

but here problem is that as project_images updated with a new object. it also updates the prop images(Add the object in the data field of images props like product_images). i don't want that prop should be changed because I'm using the old prop value. why is this strange thing happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are copied by reference, so `form.product_images` and `images.data` are referring to the same array in memory. Editing one variable would affect the other.

The solution is to deep copy the original array into a new array. One way to do that is to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array into newly [spread objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```js
data() {
  return {
    form : this.$inertia.form({
      product_images : this.images.data.map(x => ({...x})),
    }),
  }
},
```